# Is HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered broken? I keep getting nil when there is data in the health app

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm trying to grab data from the Health App. Specifically data that the user did not enter in themselves. For instance, I have an iPhone 6+ that logs the amount of steps that I take. There is also an option to add the data manually; If you add the data manually, the health app marks the data as "user added".

Here's what's confusing me. Let's say I added a step count of 22. When I query the data using HKStatisticsQuery with a predicate of

```
HKQuery.predicateForObjectsWithMetadataKey(HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered, allowedValues: [true])
```

I get the correct result of 22 steps, since I set the allowedValues to true and that I added this myself. However, when I try to set allowedValues to false, I get no results

```
HKQuery.predicateForObjectsWithMetadataKey(HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered, allowedValues: [false])
```

I do indeed have the step data in the health app, but it returned no results.

Comment: Which version of iOS have you been testing on?  Have you tried iOS 8.2?

Comment: @tshortli yes, it's 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the below possible areas to fix it:

1. did you authorized your application to access Steps data from HealthKit?
2. If your quering for steps count from your application without authorizing with HealthKit, then HealthKit will not return any exception it will simply returns the steps count which was entered from your application only if available, otherwise returns `nil`.
3. Before going to query health data, check for the authorization status for steps count using `authorizationStatusForType:` method available with HKHealthStore class.

**Update 1:**

My observations on wasUserEntered key is:

1. If user entering steps data from HEALTH app, respective `HKQuantitySample` stores `metadata` dictionary along with `HKWasUserEntered` key as *TRUE* automatically.
2. If user entering steps data from other than Apple's HEALTH app, respective health/fitness device or our application should send `metadata` dictionary with key `HKWasUserEntered` along with value as either *TRUE/FALSE*.  Otherwise, the `metadata` property will contain `nil` object.  **Hence, Apple is not applying predicate(predicate contains metadata key) on the data which don't have metadata with it.**

For debugging this metadata,  try to print your `HKQuantitySampleObject.metadata`

**Apple's implementation on metadata Vs NSPredicate:**

1. If Health data observed from Health/fitness devices, HealthKit is not adding the `metadata` dictionary to the respective health record.
2. In case of Health applications other than Apple's Health app, the developer should manually add the `metadata` dictionary for his record of health data.
3. If there is no `metadata` for a specific health record and `NSPredicate` have a constraint on `metadata` then, HealthKit completely omitting to validate such records.

Finally,

1. It is advised to use

   - (instancetype)quantitySampleWithType:(HKQuantityType *)quantityType
                               quantity:(HKQuantity *)quantity
                              startDate:(NSDate *)startDate
                                endDate:(NSDate *)endDate
                               metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata;

instead of

```
+ (instancetype)quantitySampleWithType:(HKQuantityType *)quantityType
                              quantity:(HKQuantity *)quantity
                             startDate:(NSDate *)startDate
                               endDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
```

to add metadata.

2. Reporting Apple regarding this bug that, predicate(which contains `metadata` key) should be applied on all the data irrespective of checking for `metadata` exists or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can confirm that the app indeed has access to the steps data from the health app. Like described in my post, I am able to grab the user-entered data with the predicate set with accepted values of true, but when I set it to false, I got nil. 

I have both user-entered and passively-logged step data from the iPhone 6.

Comment: Can you verify the passively-logged steps data's wasUserEntered key value is NO in HEALTH app(The app which is provided by Apple, not your application)?

Comment: As per the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Metadata_Keys

It states that if the sample is user-entered, the metadata value for wasUserEntered is YES/true, otherwise, NO/false

Comment: Thanks m8. I think I understand the problem based on what you've written. Cheers!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to create a predicate that checks if the metadata exists or not? I tried `NSPredicate(format: "%K == nil", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered)!` and Xcode crashed on me.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while and you have probably solved this by now, but I think it is worth posting here in case someone else comes across the same issue.

Like **Bhanu** mentioned, data created by Apple themselves doesn't seem to have the `HKWasUserEntered` entry as part of its metadata.

But Apple never claims to do it anyway in their docs, so the proper query would be one that filtered out items with `HKWasUserEntered == true` **if** that key was set, but also gave back everything else that had no metadata associated.

The ideia is that `metadata` is a `Dictionary`, and that type returns `nil` if a key does not exist. So there are three possible scenarios:

- `HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered == nil`
- `HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered == false`
- `HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered == true`

Out of those, you just want to filter out the last one, since that explicitly tells you that data was entered but the user.

This can be done using the `+ predicateForObjectsWithMetadataKey:operatorType:value:` convenience method on `HKQuery`, like this:

```
HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey: HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered, operatorType: .notEqualTo, value: true)
```

But of course, your initial question was: "Is HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered broken?". And I don't believe it is, since, like mentioned, Apple never claims to write that key for their own values. :)